# How to display category information from a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a page that uses custom posts: http://www.africanhealthleadership.org/resources/toolkit/

Each tool (Preparation, Assessment, etc.) is a custom post.  On the WP Admin, each tool is a category; each category has a "description" field.  I would like to output those descriptions on the Toolkit page.  I tried using this and nothing displayed: 
`<?php echo category_description( $category ); ?>`

Right now, the descriptions are hard-coded in to the page.  The one for preparation begins 
"Preparation tools establish..."

Thank you for any ideas!
Jeff

---

Here is the loop that spits out the custom post type:

```
<?php
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'toolkit' => 'preparation' ) );
//the loop start here
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And Here is the code from functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');

function portfolio_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Toolkit', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Tool', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Tool', 'tool'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Tool'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Tool'),
    'new_item' => __('New Tool'),
    'view_item' => __('View Tool'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Toolkit'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}

register_taxonomy("toolkit", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical" => true,   "label"     => "Tool Categories", "singular_label" => "Tool", "rewrite" => true));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the taxonomy term for this particular post, then what you need is `wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'yourtaxonomyname')`

This will return an array of terms in the specified taxonomy for the post specified. The codex  page is: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

If you're after a specific term in a taxonomy get_term($taxonomy_name, $term_id). You can also get all terms for a taxonomy using get_terms()

Here's an example of how to use it.

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'toolkit');  
foreach ($terms as $term) {  
    echo $term->description;  
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm confused now. Do you need the normal category taxonomy to be attached to custom posts, or do you just need to output descriptions for each of your categories (where category means an item in the normal WP category taxonomy)?

Comment: Sorry to be confusing!  I need the categories I created for the custom posts.  So, it's a taxonomy just for these posts. Does that  make sense?

Comment: gotcha - editing my answer with what I think you need

Comment: Thanks, Anu. Sorry to be a php nitwit, but I tried this and got nothing: '<?php wp_get_post_terms('20', 'toolkit', 'description') ?>'  should I have left it as '<?php wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'toolkit', 'description') ?>' ?

Comment: Added a quick code fragment

Answer (score 2):

Make you're passing the *numeric category id* into the category_description function.

The value of the variable $category won't fill itself automatically, if that's what you were expecting. You need to set it for each category you output.

If you post the relevant code (the loop you're using to sipt out that category list), it'd be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, MathSmath, I will try that.  I was being a tad literal minded! Code is above, thank you again.

Comment: MathSmath, I added the following and still don't get the cat description. I am doing something dumb, right?    `<?php
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'toolkit' => 'preparation' ) );
  //the loop start here
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php echo category_description('20'); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>`

Comment: Jeff, please add the loop's code inside your original question as it is much better to read then.

Comment: I think category_description() only works for the default category taxonomy - not a custom taxonomy