# Uploading files in admin panel?

Tags: admin, uploads, theme-options

I want to allow my users to upload files in admin panel, but I'm not sure where should I upload these files and how the script should look like?

```
<p>Please provide link to a file or click "Upload" to upload it from your PC:</p>
<form>
Link: <input type="text" name ="logo_url">
Upload: <input type="file" name="logo_file">
<input type="Submit" value="Upload">
```

How should back-end look for that script? I mean the type="file" part :)

Oh and of course I have fully working theme option page (so the first input works like a charm).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an image upload field directly to a custom write panel?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-can-i-add-an-image-upload-field-directly-to-a-custom-write-panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [very similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-can-i-add-an-image-upload-field-directly-to-a-custom-write-panel/4413#4413). The answer can be adjusted to work with all types of files, not just images.

Answer (score -2):

If you use the [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin your visitors can upload an attachment to a file that sends you an email with the file as an attachment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Contact Form, and I'm looking for an answer not connected to any plugin, I just want to understand the concept and then write my own php script. Thanks anyway.