# mp4 video preview

Tags: videos

Our webpage is using WordPress 4.2.1 running Virtue - Premium theme.

When I insert a video using visual editor, e.g.

```
[video width="1280" height="720" mp4="http://F6tech.com/wp-content/uploads/../../test.mp4"][/video]
```

There is no preview on the webpage.  It just shows a black video screen with an arrow.

Is it possible to display a still from the tenth second of the video instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add a thumbnail with the [`[video]`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode) shortcode by making use of the `poster` attribute.

If you want to do it automatically, then you have to implement `FFMPEG` or `LIBAV` first, meaning they would have to be available on your server. Afterwards you could hook into `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` and automate process - I have given an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/121633/22534) how to do this for PDF's some time ago, just so you get an idea. But that of course will be quite some work.

I hear there are some pretty good plug-ins in the [WordPress Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/), although I haven't used them myself.