# image upload error wordpress

Tags: plugins, uploads

i am trying to upload image it is uploaded successfully but when i tried to access it in phpmysql the link is somethig like this : http://localhost/job/?attachment_id=40

i want to store this image url like this: http://localhost/job/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Koala.jpg

here is code to upload image:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['photo_rcb'])) {
                                $file   = $_FILES['photo_rcb'];
                                $upload = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
                              //  print_r($upload);exit;
                                if(!isset($upload['error']) && isset($upload['file'])) {
                                    $filetype   = wp_check_filetype(basename($upload['file']), null);
                                    $title      = $file['name'];
                                    $ext        = strrchr($title, '.');
                                    $title      = ($ext !== false) ? substr($title, 0, -strlen($ext)) : $title;
                                    $attachment = array(
                                        'post_mime_type'    => $wp_filetype['type'],
                                        'post_title'        => addslashes($title),
                                        'post_content'      => '',
                                        'post_status'       => 'inherit',
                                        'post_author'       => $user_id
                                    );

                                        $attach_key = 'document_file_id';
                                        $attach_id  = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $upload['file']);


                                        update_user_meta($user_id,'photo_rcb', $attach_id);
                                  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Retrieve the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Images should upload in that format when using wp_handle_upload. It is unclear exactly how you are getting http://localhost/job/?attachment_id=40

I would suggest having something similar to the **Handling the File Upload** section of this post:

- [How can I add an image upload field directly to a custom write panel?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/how-can-i-add-an-image-upload-field-directly-to-a-custom-write-panel/4413#4413)

Answer (score 0):

One of the greatest problems with WordPress is the picture upload issue, which has neither a clear cause nor a clear fix. This picture upload difficulty is caused by several factors, and various fixes are available. Actually, it's hard to forecast when anything will happen, and it occasionally happens at random.
is that image uploaded error occurring with all types of images?
If every image you have has an uploading problem:

1. alter the file's permissions.
2. Plugins should be disabled, especially those that enhance photos.
3. Increase the WordPress and PHP memory limitations for your website.
4. On the Media Settings screen, delete the file path.
5. See if your PHP version is the source of the problem.
   you can try several types of solutions for uploading images without any error in WordPress. I would suggest some ways to fix your error with image uploading. So try this "[Fix the Image Upload Issue in WordPress](https://trendyport.com/how-to-fix-the-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/)" and fix your problem and get free from that issue.