# Getting Wordpress custom taxonomy/category?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Well, I'm using my own taxonomy for custom post type. It looks like this:

```
register_taxonomy("our_gallery", array("gallery"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Types", "singular_label" => "Type", "rewrite" => true));
```

I have created a few "types"/categories in my admin panel like "Black and white", "Landscapes" and so forth...

Anyways I can't figure out how to get these categories out? I mean - display them on my gallery page just next to gallery items?

I've tried:

```
  <?php $cat = get_the_category();
    var_dump($cat); ?>
```

And it displays an empty array - "array(0) { }". How to get access to my own categories? get_the_category('our gallery') and ('gallery') also gives an empty array...

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This question has been answered quite a few times now - should we be pointing to existing answers instead of answering it again?

Comment: @anu if you know a duplicate question please include a link to it in comment. Users with 500+ rep can [cast close votes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) and cite duplicate as reason, I just can't remember exact match to this one myself. :)

Comment: This: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4291/ is pretty much the same question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are getting confused by terminology here.

*Category* is a `taxonomy`. Specific categories you create are `terms`.

*our_gallery* is `taxonomy`. *Landscapes* is `term`. *our_gallery* is **not** `category`. It is its own `taxonomy` and has nothing to do with *category* `taxonomy`.

[`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) function explicitly fetches `terms` of *category* `taxonomy`.

To get `terms` of *our_gallery* `taxonomy` you need more generic function [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

Comment: Got it! Can you help me with getting 'landscape' out o this? array(1) { [17]=> object(stdClass)#378 (10) { ["term_id"]=> string(2) "17" ["name"]=> string(5) "Image" ["slug"]=> string(5) "image" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["taxonomy"]=> string(18) "our_gallery" ["description"]=>

Comment: Please add any code and followup to your question and markup it as such. Comments are no good for that.

Comment: You can use `the_terms($post->ID, 'our_gallery')` to automatically display a comma separated list for the current post.

Comment: But it still displays a link, not paragraph...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use following statement to get categories of a taxonomy:

```
$taxonomy  = 'your-taxonomy-name';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
```